# What is this grey-leaved plant, low shrub good for dry conditions?

Tags: identification

Grey-leaved plant about 1m high and can survive tough conditions. It is a common plant in Australian gardens.

[image]

Comment: Looks vaguely like a sedum, but I have no idea what's common in Australia.

Comment: Am thinking sedum, too, but can you describe the flowers? Or, even better, have a picture? Welcome, btw!

Answer (score 1):

It might be Cotyledon undulata - you haven't said whether it flowers, but this plant produces orangey bell shaped flowers. In most parts of the world, its a houseplant, with leaves which grow closer together than on this one, but it originates from South Africa, where it grows outdoors and looks somewhat 'looser' than when kept inside in a pot. If your temperatures regularly drop below 32 deg F, though, or leaves are not fleshy as they look to be in the picture, it won't be that.